# Криво работает условный оператор в javascript

Tags: javascript, if, условия

Вопрос в том почему третий месяц программа считает зимним

```
if (myMonth == 01 || myMonth == 02 || myMonth==12) {
  document.write("Время года: зима");

} else if (myMonth > 02 || myMonth ==04 || myMonth ==05) {
  document.write("Время года: весна");

} else {
  document.write("Время года: s");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код не дописан но уже сейчас работает неверно

Comment: Если что, `new Date().getMonth()` - начинает отсчет с нуля, т.е. 0 - январь. Приведите полный пример кода в виде текста, а не картинки.

Comment: так ты же сам из третьего месяца вычитаешь единицу и получаешь цифру 2

Comment: а вот эта часть условия `if (myMonth > 02` никого не смутила. А ошибочка то здесь

Comment: @KoVadim там не эта ошибочка

Comment: ошибка в вычитании  из месяца единицы

Comment: вычитание единицы это другой, рядом стоящий баг

Comment: Меня не смутило, потому что я код картинкой не смотрел :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myMonth == 01 || myMonth == 02 || myMonth == 12) {
 text = "Время года: зима";
} else if (myMonth == 03 || myMonth == 04 || myMonth == 05) {
 text = "Время года: весна";
} else if (myMonth == 06 || myMonth == 07 || myMonth == 08) {
 text = "Время года: лето";
} else {
 text = "Время года: осень";
}
document.write(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

О, раз уж в комментариях уже ответили, что ошибка вы вычитании, то я тоже хочу принять участие в оптимизации кода в ответах.

```js
document.getElementById("result").onclick = _ => {
    let number = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
    document.getElementById("answer").innerText = 
        ["зима","весна","лето","осень"][Math.floor(number / 3) % 4];
}
```

```html
<div>
  Введите номер месяца [01-12]: <input id="num" type="text" /> 
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <button id="result">Вывести название времени года</button>
</div>
<div id="answer" />
```